# VBA script always returns Input past end of file error

Tags: string, vba, csv, ms-word

I have a csv file as such:

```
hello,world,this
is,an,example,
of,the,csv,file
```

The first column will always be unique.

I am getting the user to enter a string which matches an item in the first column, and the script returns the whole line:

```
Open "C:\file1.csv" For Input As #file_number
Do While (EOF(1) Or found = False)
    Line Input #file_number, raw_line
    pos = InStr(raw_line, fireName)
    If pos = Not 0 Then
        strData() = Split(raw_line, ",")
        found = True
    End If
Loop
Close #file_number
If found = False Then
    MsgBox "Could not find it"
    Exit Sub
End If
'REST OF THE CODE
```

But it always sends the message "could not find it" and exits.
By default, found is a boolean value and is false.

I know it can detect the file as when I changed the read file name, it created a new one (as it does not exist).

EDIT:
I changed the `And` to an `Or` and now I get the error: 
`Run-time error 62: input past end of file`

Comment: Probably not creating any issues (since you presumably only have one file open), but `EOF(1)` checks a hard-coded file number and you open it as #file_number.  It should be `EOF(file_number)`.

Comment: @Comintern I do have only one file open

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a simple error in your `Do While` loop. You Check for the EOF instead of not the EOF, as such the loop will never execute since it starts at the BOF.

Something like this should work (my syntax may be slightly off as I haven't used VBA in a while)

```
Open "C:\file1.csv" For Input As #file_number
While Not EOF(file_number) And found <> False
    Line Input #file_number, raw_line
    pos = InStr(raw_line, fireName)
    If pos <> 0 Then
        strData() = Split(raw_line, ",")
        found = True
    End If
Wend
Close #file_number
If found = False Then
    MsgBox "Could not find it"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: When I try it this way, even if the word is not found, it does not send the msgbox

Comment: I added a `Not` to the `If pos = ` statement, it makes more sense now, but now it always returns a `could not find it` message.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of typing `If pos != 0` in VBA is

```
If pos <> 0
```

Now it works